# Icon Is not clickable on mobile view

Tags: mudblazor

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BzGjN.png)We are using Mudblazor library. While using it we are using mudtable component. We add info. icon in the column header, icon is not clickable in the mobile view.

In desktop view icon is clickable. Adding margin and padding is giving extra spaces.

Comment: sample code:- 


<MudTh> <MudTableSortLabel SortLabel="IsInternal">Standard Text <MudPaper><QuickHelp HelpMessageType="" /></MudPaper></MudTableSortLabel> </MudTh>

Comment: What does 'QuickHelp' look like? Please include your relevant code in the question.